# Vincent plots are not showing up, not receiving errors

Tags: python, plot, vincent

For some reason I am getting the below when I try and plot something with Vincent:

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML at 0x10db19650>
<IPython.core.display.Javascript at 0x10db19d50>
```

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import vincent

data = pd.read_csv('kd.csv')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[data['Age'], data['FG'], data['FGA'], data['3P'], data['3PA']])
df = df.T

df[['FG', 'FGA', '3P', '3PA']] = df[['FG', 'FGA', '3P', '3PA']].astype(float)

line = vincent.Line(df)

line.display()
```

This happens in IPython and Ipython Notebook.  Any idea why?

Comment: You'll need to add the code that's causing the above output.
Are you calling `.display()`?

Comment: Yes, I am.  Code is above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you found answer yet but it's a simple solution.

```
import vincent as v
v.core.initialize_notebook()
```

From there your plots should render correctly within Ipython notebook. A call to `line.display()` is unnecessary.