# Unable to display Vincent sample maps; no suggested solutions work

Tags: python, dictionary, canopy, vincent

This is the same question as [each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089935/unable-plot-with-vincent-in-ipython) of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480426/unable-to-plot-using-vincent) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212336/vincent-plots-are-not-showing-up-not-receiving-errors?rq=1), but none of the suggested solutions are working for me.

I'm trying to make a US State map in Python with the Vincent package, as shown in [this tutorial](http://wrobstory.github.io/2013/10/mapping-data-python.html). I'm using the Canopy editor. When I run this code, nothing shows up in my console. There are no errors that appear.

- I've placed us_states.topo.json in my Python working directory.
- I updated Canopy and Vincent.
- I'm using vincent.core.initialize_notebook() as well as vis.display() like some other users have suggested.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong....

```
import vincent

vincent.core.initialize_notebook()

state_topo = 'us_states.topo.json'

geo_data = [{'name': 'states',
             'url': state_topo,
             'feature': 'us_states.geo'},
             ]

vis = vincent.Map(geo_data=geo_data, scale=1000, projection='albersUsa')
vis.to_json('vega.json')
vis.display()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm correct Canopy editor can't render Vincent output.

You should use Vincent on the IPython/Jupyter notebook or just output the [json to display it on a browser](https://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#output). The code on your example with some minor modifications is:

```
import vincent

vincent.core.initialize_notebook()
state_topo = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wrobstory/vincent_map_data/master/us_states.topo.json"
geo_data = [{'name': 'states',
             'url': state_topo,
             'feature': 'us_states.geo'}]

vis = vincent.Map(geo_data = geo_data, scale = 500, projection = 'albersUsa')
vis.to_json('vega.json')
vis.display()
```

And the output in an IPython/Jupyter notebook can be seen in the image below:

[image]

BTW, it seems Vincent is [not updated and it wouldn't be](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent#2015-08-12-update). So, have a look for alternatives (e.g., [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html)) if you don't want to use obsolete software.

Comment: Thanks very much! Mystery solved. I was using Bokeh for a while, but their maps don't display Michigan-- which is a bit of a problem since I work in Michigan! I guess I'll just have to work around that, then.